# Add new Document into field type Json through Waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-orientdb

I am trying to add a new document or you can say a new key value pair to an existing json type field, but it is replacing the older key value pair e.g.
before my embedded field was `{"@type":"d","key1":"example1"}`
and when I executed the update call

```
WL_MODELS.numbers.update({id: req.body.SID},{numbers: {"key2":"example2"}},function(err,model){ if(err) console.log(err); else {  console.log(model);}} );
```

it replaces the value of `numbers: {"@type":"d","key2":"example2"}`
but i want to add the new key value pair inside the existing embedded or json document, if my method is wrong then tell me how can i do it using waterline and sails-orientdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xeeB, in waterline `json` is a datatype just like `integer` or `string` and similarly to those you can't perform nested operations against it. In other words, doing `.update(criteria, { attribute: json })` will replace the whole `json` object which is what you are experiencing.

To achieve what you want you'll first need to get the json, before changing it, for example:

```
WL_MODELS.numbers.findOne({id: req.body.SID}, function(err, model){
  model.numbers["key2"] = "example2";
  model.save(function(err){
    console.log("saved:", model);
  });
});
```

Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: but I have a question can i use it with promises like           WL_MODELS.numbers.findOne({id : id}).then(function(model){ model['key'] = "example"; model.save(); }).catch(function(err){ console.log(err);  });